# Creating Lua Advanced Table

Tags: multidimensional-array, insert, lua, lua-table

Need to create some table so I can get an info from it in this way:

```
table[attacker][id]
```

And if I'll use

```
print(table[attacker][id])
```

It should print the **value**.

Tried many ways, but haven't found any good ...

I guess it should be something like this...

```
table.insert(table, attacker, [id] = value)
```

^ This does not work.

Can someone help me?

---

**Edit**

Well, when I try it this way:

```
x = {}
function xxx()
    if not x[attacker][cid] then
        x[attacker][cid] = value
    else
        x[attacker][cid] = x[attacker][cid] + value
    end
    print(x[attacker][cid])
end
```

I get an error saying:

> attempt to index field '?' (a nil value)

Comment: That error means exactly what it says... `x[attacker]` is apparently `nil`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the curly braces to create the inner table:

```
table.insert(my_table, attacker, {[id]=value})
```

or

```
-- the advantage of this is that it works even if 'attacker' isn't a number
my_table[attacker] = {[id]=value}
```

---

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = {}
table.insert(d, a, {[b]=c})
print(d[a][b]) -- prints '3'
```

Comment: This only works if `attacker` is an integer, as table.insert only works inserting values into the array part of the table.

Comment: Sure. Of course, normal table assignment syntax can also work for non-integer keys; I was simply adapting the OP's example to the nearest thing that would work.

Comment: btw. attacker is an integer always,

Answer (score 2):

What is `attacker`? That is, what value does it contain? It doesn't *really* matter what it contains since Lua tables can use any Lua value as a key. But it would be useful to know.

In any case, it's really simple.

```
tableName = {}; --Note: your table CANNOT be called "table", as that table already exists as part of the Lua standard libraries.
tableName[attacker] = {}; --Create a table within the table.
tableName[attacker][id] = value; --put a value in the table within the table.
```

---

The problem in your edit happened because you didn't take note of step 2 above. Values in a Lua table are empty (nil) until they have a value. Therefore, until line 2, `tableName[attacker]` is **nil**. You cannot index a nil value. You therefore *must* ensure that any keys in `tableName` that you expect to index into are in fact tables.

To put it another way, you cannot do `tableName[attacker][id]` unless you *know* that `type(tableName[attacker]) == "table"` is true.

Answer (score 1):

you should use `table = {['key']='value'}` makes it easier.